# Calling multiple shell scripts within a script on different virtual machines

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to create shell scripts which will setup Zookeeper Server in one VM, and its corresponding Zookeeper Clients in different VM's so i written a shell script as below

```
#!/bin/bash

ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP="1.2.3.4"

while read  ipaddress zookeepertype number
do

        echo -e "Setting up the Zookeepers \n"

        echo $ipaddress

        if [ "${zookeepertype}" = 'zookeeperserver' ]; then

                echo "Setup Zookeeper Server"

                        #ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP = $ipaddress

                        #echo $ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP

                        #echo $ipaddress

                        sudo scp -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd -r /home/ubuntu/ZooKeeper_Server_Script.sh ubuntu@$ipaddress:/home/ubuntu/

                        ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd ubuntu@$ipaddress /home/ubuntu/ZooKeeper_Server_Script.sh

                        echo "This script is about to run ZooKeeper_Server_Script."

                        echo "The server script has completed.";

                       #sleep 30

                        exit 1

       fi

        echo -e $ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP

        if [ $zookeepertype = "zookeeperclient" ] ; then

                        echo "Setup Zookeeper Client"

                        echo $ipaddress

                        sudo scp -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd -r /home/ubuntu/ZooKeeper_Client_Script.sh ubuntu@$ipaddress:/home/ubuntu/

                        ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd ubuntu@$ipaddress

                        #mkdir /home/ubuntu/keyfiles

                        #exit


                        #sudo scp -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd -r /home/ubuntu/abc/network/test/keyfiles/* ubuntu@$ipaddress:/home/ubuntu/keyfiles

                        #sudo scp -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd -r /home/ubuntu/abc/test/simple/abc.json ubuntu@$ipaddress:/home/ubuntu/

                        #ssh -i /home/ubuntu/.ssh/fd ubuntu@$ipaddress

                        #chmod 777 ZooKeeper_Client_Script.sh

                        #echo "This script is about to run ZooKeeper_Client_Script."

                        #sh ./ZooKeeper_Client_Script.sh $ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP

                        echo "The client script has completed."

                        #exit

                fi

        #Separating Runhosts File

done < setupZkinput.txt
```

the input file is 
1.2.3.4 zookeeperserver 1
5.6.7.8 zookeeperclient 2
9.10.11.12 zookeeperclient 3

The issue that i am facing is

1) Only the server setup is being done , i.e the script is exiting after the first line
2)Not able to assign the server ip dynamically , in the line ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_IP = $ipaddress

Thanks

Comment: I tried to remove the first if loop then the second loop got executed but only one time though it had to execute multiple times.

Comment: if i comment the shell script execution then it prints all the ip address and entire loop is completed , if i am enable once one script execution is done it stops

Answer (score 0):

What is the default permission you are setting up after copying a file to the server?
remember it required execute permission in order to execute script.

Comment: The Script is getting executed in the first server, but it is exiting without executing in other servers, the while loop is getting terminated after the first script execution

Comment: I see  exit in the loop, I think thats is the reason, it is getting terminated.


                        echo "The server script has completed.";

                       #sleep 30

                        exit 1

Comment: can you please provide me sample output after executing code?